# Issue with embedded SVG images in dark mode

Tags: css, svg, media-queries

Embedded svg image inside  tag doesn't work with media query prefers-color-scheme and CSS variables (Chrome and Safari, Firefox works).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="var(--color)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <style>
        :root{--color:#ffffff;}
        @media(prefers-color-scheme:light){:root{--color:#ffffff;}}
        @media(prefers-color-scheme:dark){:root{--color:#000000;}}
    </style>
    <path d="M18 15l-6-6-6 6"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What is your question? What should be the expected output? Read the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: The SVG is embedded in <img>. In enabled dark mode, it should use the color for the dark sheme. But in Chrome and Safari it takes the same color like the global CSS sheet. So the image isn't visible at all. The CSS style sheet shouldn't affect the embedded SVG image. Is there a way, to change the color of embedded SVG images in dark mode? (currentColor doesn't work either)..

Comment: So you are asking why a `<img>` isn't showing? If so, please edit your post to include code about the `<img>` that isn't showing. Also, edit your post to ask **question**, it should include a question mark.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  width="48" height="48">
  <style>
    :root { --color: #00FF00; }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { :root { --color: #0000FF; } }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { :root { --color: #FF0000; } }
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: var(--color);
      stroke-width: 3;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
  </style>
  <path d="M18 15l-6-6-6 6"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I just verified that this technique works in Safari and Brave. One thing I will mention is that to get this working in Safari, I ad to embed the image using the `object` tag, not the `img` tag. e.g. `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>`

Thanks @Vino.

Comment: I found this link which mentions why you need <object> instead of <img>:
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-svg-with-media-queries/#svgandtheimgelementlimitations