# SVG dark mode styling doesn't work in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, ios-darkmode, macos-darkmode

Site body dark mode styling works well on both Chrome and Safari for me by CSS variables with `prefers-color-scheme`.

But there is a different situation with logo. I've styled external .svg inside of it with styling for dark mode and light mode, which works perfectly for Chrome. But on macOS and iOS Safari it doesn't change it's colour.

What can be the possible solution?

Thank you

Comment: It depends which version of Safari you are testing on -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=prefers-color-scheme

Comment: No, the things is that HTML with CSS styling for dark mode works well on Safari. I mean, all the site becomes dark when you did switch dark mode on your iPhone or macBook, but logo doesn't change in Safari, while it does it in Chrome.

Comment: Do you embed the logo in a `<img>` tag - it works under Firefox and Chrome? For me it's only working if I embed the SVG inline.

Comment: Duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493483/issue-with-embedded-svg-images-in-dark-mode
?