# Creating SVG that appears black in light mode and light in dark mode

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a logo that will need to appear in the header and footer of a website I am  working on, and the site has an option to toggle between light and dark mode. I need the black elements of the logo to appear black when the dark mode is on, and light when the light mode is on. I have tried the following CSS:

svg {
fill:="currentColor"}

but for some reason that causes the black elements to disappear entirely instead of setting them to the default color. How can I make this work? The only other potential solution I am aware of is to convert the svg to a font and then imbed that in the site, but I would like to avoid doing that if it all possible.

Comment: Please note that you are using invalid css, `:="currentColor"`  should be

```css
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can add CSS to your SVG directly. For example, here's one that directly using the browsers light / dark settings

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
   <style>
        path {
            fill: black;
        }
        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
            path { fill: white; }
        }
    </style>
    <path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

**WARNING**: the following part of my answer is untested and might not work for an .svg source in an `<img>` tag, or even for an `<svg>` tag. If someone tests it, please comment below so I can edit my answer and not provide misleading information.

If you are using something else to "trigger" the dark theme, you can just change the media query to whatever else you need, like a global class:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
   <style>
        path {
            fill: black;
        }
        body.dark-theme path {
            fill: white;
        }
    </style>
    <path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer.

The assumption here is that this SVG is inline, not loaded as part of an `img` or `object`.

Comment: @MXDVL it should work in those too, although you might need to restart the browser.

Comment: I should have clarified that while the media query approach will work, I don’t think an SVG inside an `img` tag has access to the page’s CSS styles.

Comment: yep I think @MXDVL is right, and the 2nd part of my answer is wrong (even inline maybe?) Can someone check so that I edit my answer and not leave something misleading?

Comment: This works perfect. I just read an entire article regarding this, and I still had no solution until I found this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure to do the stroke color also.  <style>* {fill: black;stroke:white}body.dark-theme path {fill: white;stroke:black}</style>

Comment: This is, hands down, the best answer on the internet for this.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your css to the following:

```css
svg { fill=currentColor }
```

It is possible that your icons are appearing to disappear because they are black on a black background. Also check if they are implemented using `stroke` rather than `fill` - post your svg to answer that.

Also note that there is a built-in `prefers-color-scheme` css media query that allows this. More information in the links below.

### References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme
- [Issue with embedded SVG images in dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493483/issue-with-embedded-svg-images-in-dark-mode)
- https://css-tricks.com/dark-mode-favicons/
- https://web.dev/prefers-color-scheme/
- https://caniuse.com/?search=prefers-color-scheme

Comment: This solution is a lot nicer as it makes all SVGs consistent and gives the ability to use CSS variables

Comment: You do need to be clever with your logo, especially when people have 'middling colour' or photo themes ... best is to test test test in as many browsers and on as many devices (both pc, mac and mobile / tablet) as you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it with a CSS class
just add a CSS class to the body when dark mode is on let's say `darkMode`
then set fill colors based on it

```js
function myFunction() {
      document.querySelector("#body").classList.toggle('darkMode');
}
```

```css
.darkMode{
background:black;
height:100vh;
}
svg{ fill:black;}
.darkMode svg {fill:white;}
```

```html
<div id="body">
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg> 
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggel</button>
</div>
```