# Maui svg icons with light and dark theme styles

Tags: maui, .net-maui

Is it possible to set the style of the svg icon based on if the Maui app is in light/dark theme? I know that Microsoft suggests creating two separate files, one for light and one for dark themes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes

But it would be much more useful to have a single svg file and set the styling within the file: [Creating SVG that appears black in light mode and light in dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187091/creating-svg-that-appears-black-in-light-mode-and-light-in-dark-mode)

Can an svg `<style>` setter be conditional to the AppTheme in Maui apps?

Comment: No, has to be two separate SVGs. Maui converts each SVG to a PNG, so that the image is compatible with all platforms. AFAIK, there is no general way to have a single PNG respond to theme. OTOH, if your icon is stored as a single color (white or black), each platform is capable of "colorizing" an image. So it is possible to have a one-color icon that changes with theme. I don't know if Maui has a cross-platform way to do this, or if you need a custom renderer on each platform.

Comment: Yeah, Maui community toolkit has an IconColorTintBehavior. It works with ios and android. But not for Windows. I knew svg files were converted to a png, but I was hoping it could assign the color based on the theme when converting to the png.

Comment: It can't, because the conversion is done at **build** time, not at **run** time. At run-time, there is no svg. Unfortunately, there is no built-in mechanism to keep track of two different pngs, to pick the right one at run-time, by itself. [And if there was, there would be no reason to support this obscure svg mechanism. Instead, it would be similar to Apple's "assets": a design-time UI for dragging two images into one container, with slots for different themes.]

Comment: I don't want to keep track of the two different pngs, only the one that is built at build time (whether that was built will fill black or fill white (for example). It would be built based on the AppTheme. So it does not have the choice of choosing black/white at run time, but rather only one png is built.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. Either your app responds at run-time to a theme change, or it does not. If it does respond, then you need both. If it does not respond, then you force it to the theme you want at app startup, ignoring OS theme. OR you create styles for all Maui elements, that specify the elements to use, with no mention of theme. Thus, there is no way for OS theme to affect your app.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. So if a user changes the System Theme, then there is no way of reloading the svg files to recreate the png and reset the source because it is all done at build time.

Comment: I totally agreed. And i thought something different. It seems that you could do some image process of your svg files according to theme. Skiasharp could be used to manipulate image, such as color filter and blend modes.  Maybe you could render your image according to theme styles.